# All recent changes in MySQL database has removed automatically. Newly, Inserted data is not available

Tags: mysql

I'm using mySQL just for few months.

I'm entering some data into it with PHP code.

Actually, I'm entering this data for last two month. And till yesterday everything is fine.

But when I open it in myphpadmin today i didn't see the data of last 10 days but before 10 days every data is there.

There is two table in which i'm entering the data and i didn't find anything in both table for last 10 days. I clearly remind that i didn't execute any delete query and no one is used my machine.

What could be the problem. Or, how could i get the data?

Update:
Now, I have notice a miracle things. In this 10 days I have updated many data i entered before this 10 days But all of them like as before. That means, It seems that what happen in database in this 10 day all are vanish and restore the database as it's like 10 days before.

Comment: Check your [**PHP error logs**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel) for errors when saving the data.

Comment: @Martin, I think my database is restored to 10 days previous version. How it has done I don't know. What should I look into error logs file?

Comment: @Martin https://pastebin.com/FX1xP5eX   Here is the error log. I don't find anything wrong.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. That looks like the MySQL error log rather than the PHP error log. the PHP one may be useful as well. Can you open that one? Cheers